# How do I write to an xls file in Java?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, csv, xls

I am coding a program that requires me to write to an excel sheet. I have dragged the file into my Eclipse project and I have used the "PrintWriter" method to write to the file. I have imported the necessary libraries, however when I run my program and press enter to write to the file, I do not get an error, nor does it write to the file as expected. Can someone help me? Much thanks. My code is here:

```
JButton addClientButton = new JButton("Add");
        addClientButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {
                    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Client Details.csv"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(firstNameTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(lastNameTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(emailTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(phoneTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(weightTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(heightTextField.getText());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(ageSpinner.getValue());
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(activityLevelComboBox.getSelectedItem());

                pw.write(sb.toString());
                pw.close();
            }
        });
        addClientButton.setBounds(374, 335, 89, 23);
        newClients.add(addClientButton);
```

Comment: What you are printing is a comma separated file (csv) that can be opened with excel. This said, there should be an End Of Line at the end of the line. I don't know if that is the cause but try adding sb.append("\n"); before the write.

Comment: would this link help you out. https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/